# How to use webapi for uploading and downloading any files from Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

So there is a webapi in ASP.NET that i'm working on and the requirement is to accept an image(file, in general) from webapp built on React and give the file back upon request. The storage service being used is Azure Blob Storage.
I'm new to this environment and I'm all finding is tutorial on how to upload file through console or direct app and not through api. I need to know what to send through react app, so that my webapi can accept and upload it to the Blob Storage and what to send through my api to the webapp, with example code.

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? Is that you want to know how to directly  upload file to azure blob in react app?

Comment: no, actually i'm building an api in ASP.NET and I want to make apis for uploading and downloading a file which will be consumed by the webapp which is built on react. One solution I found was to get byte string of the image and directly store it to Blob Storage but in this case I need to implement converting the image in react itself and then sending it to my api. I want to know better way to do it.

Comment: Please chekc my amswer

Comment: Thanks, the code works for the api. And also it uses Azure namespace nuget package, not the deprecated one. Only one problem though, i tried testing using react it gives me 'net::err_cert_authority_invalid react' error as axios only works in https, I guess. And I didnt find any good source to resolve that issue. But the code works when tested using Postman. Could you also provide the download part too? Thanks again, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, you can send your image file as form data to your API. For more details, please refer to the following steps

- **Client**

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
  const [isFilePicked, setIsFilePicked] = useState(false);

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    setIsFilePicked(true);
  };

  const onFileUpload = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", selectedFile);
    formData.append("fileName", selectedFile.name);
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "https://localhost:44349/weatherforecast",
        formData
      );
      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
      {isFilePicked ? (
        <div>
          <p>Filename: {selectedFile.name}</p>
          <p>Filetype: {selectedFile.type}</p>
          <p>Size in bytes: {selectedFile.size}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Select a file to show details</p>
      )}
      <div>
        <button onClick={onFileUpload}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

- **Server**

1. [Configure CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

2. Api

```
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync([FromForm] FileModel model)
        {
            try {

                string connectionString = "";
                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
                var sourceContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("output");
                var blob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobClient(model.file.FileName);

                await blob.UploadAsync(model.file.OpenReadStream(), new BlobUploadOptions()
                {
                    HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders() { 
                      ContentType= model.file.ContentType
                    }
                });
                // Process uploaded files
                // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created); ;

            } catch (Exception) {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
           
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Azure Storage NuGet package to your project and then use the in-built classes in package to upload your files to Azure Blob Storage.

You can find a base on the same [here](https://factorycode.wordpress.com/2019/06/13/upload-files-in-azure-blob-storage-using-asp-net-core-web-api/) and [here](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/02/07/upload-a-file-to-azure-blob-storage-using-web-api/)

Comment: The nuget package used in the links are deprecated ones. It actually break my other references in the project when installed the package, so I had to uninstall it.

Comment: okay, those might have been deprecated. Can you select the Latest Stable version while installing the packages. The latest stable release of that NuGet package should not break your project files